# Adjust size of all big images with CSS

Tags: css

I have a HTML page that contains some big images.

So I would like to adjust the size of the images to the width of the surrounding text.

Best would be if only pictures that are too big would be resized. But smaller
pictures would keep their size.

If possible I would prefer a CSS only solution.

BTW: The page is generated by Doxygen and some of the big images are generated with graphviz (dot).

Thx

Comment: Show some code please

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle example?

Comment: CSS can't detect *big*. You'll have to set some parameters and show us what you have tried or explain in greater detail what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve it with `img {max-width: 100%;}`.

Comment: Thank you! That worked for me...